# List of all base packages installed in Ubuntu laptop versus Ubuntu tablet/smartphone

Tags: package-management

Please direct me to lists containing all base and mandatory packages installed in:

(1) Ubuntu Lap(desk) top

(2) Ubuntu smartphone/tablet

I wish to know the difference between the packages installed and the individual functionalities each package provide to the respective systems.

Answer (score 0):

To list the Files that you have installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

To copy the Packages to desktop in `.txt` that you have installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

To list the packages that you have installed:

```
dpkg -l
apt --installed list
```

Note: `sudo` is not necessary for the above two commands

Comment: Please send me a list of installed files for my tab. I don't have ubuntu running on my tab yet. Just trying to get an idea. Thanks for writing a reply to my post.